# Jquery write inside the draggable div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery UI library. I want to give the feature of writing text inside the draggable div on the single click. I want when the user single click the div, the cursor should appear and the user can write the text inside it.

Pls suggest the solution with the working code sample.

This is the sample code:-

```
<script>
      $(function() { 
             $( "#dv1" ).draggable();    
         });
</script>

<div id="dv1">
<p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to make the same div element editable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built further on Jesse's solution, swapping the textarea back for a paragraph when the textarea loses focus. This ensures that you can drag the `div` after editing its contents.

Check out [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/aW8ZY/)!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a textarea within the draggable container and show it on the click:

http://jsfiddle.net/GwTt3/

```
<div id="dv1">
    <p>Drag me around<textarea></textarea></p>
</div>​

​#dv1 p textarea{
 display: none;   
}​

$("#dv1").draggable(); 
$('p').on('click', function(){
   $(this).find('textarea').show(); 
});
```

​
Another option would be to add the textarea dynamically:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrHHb/

```
$( "#dv1" ).draggable();

$('p').on('click', function(e) {
   var replace = $(this);    
   var ele = $('<textarea>')
       .val(replace.text())
       .insertAfter(replace);

   replace.hide();    
});
```

​